# Why does this only cause 'ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable' when there are multiple columns?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where a column is filled with python lists, and I want to set some of the entries to an empty python list. This of course isn't the exact data I am working with, but a similar example.

This code below works

```
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11,12]]
})

# Set rows 1, 3, 5 to empty lists
df.loc[[1,3,5], 'Column'] = [[],[],[]]
print(df)
```

output

```
    Column
0   [1, 2]
1       []
2   [5, 6]
3       []
4  [9, 10]
5       []
```

but when I add an extra column to the dataframe it causes this error

```
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11,12]],
    'B':[0,1,0,1,0,1]
})

# Set rows 1, 3, 5 to empty lists
df.loc[[1,3,5], 'Column'] = [[],[],[]]
print(df)
```

it causes this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-f7459ad16c49> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 
      9 # Set rows 1, 3, 5 to empty lists
---> 10 df.loc[[1,3,5], 'Column'] = [[],[],[]]
     11 print(df)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer_2d_value(self, indexer, value)
   1898         value = np.array(value, dtype=object)
   1899         if len(ilocs) != value.shape[1]:
-> 1900             raise ValueError(
   1901                 "Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray"
   1902             )

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

any help as to why this is happening, and how I can avoid this would be much appreciated :)

I have tried changing the column type to object, and I have tried changing the shape of the lists of lists that I am adding, but to no avail.

## SOLUTION

```
df.loc[[1,3,5], 'Column'] = pd.Series([[],[],[]], index=df.index[[1,3,5]])
```

and then this is a faster version of the code that works well on the original full data

```
mask = df['B'] == 1
n = np.sum(mask)
df.loc[mask, 'Column'] = pd.Series(np.empty((n,0)).tolist(), index=df.index[mask])
```

output

```
    Column  B
0   [1, 2]  0
1       []  1
2   [5, 6]  0
3       []  1
4  [9, 10]  0
5       []  1
```

Comment: ok, it works, but I still don't understand the essence as why we need the pd.Series() other then it helps to encapsulate the none-scalar value...